# Load Data Local Infile Issues

Tags: mysql

OK i'm trying to upload a txt file into my table. My issue is with the field terminator. I have tried using several characters but nothing wants to work. My last attempt was with a '.'

txt file:

```
John. B. Smith. 123456789. 1955-01-09. 731 Fondren, Cary, NC. M. 30000. 333445555. 5.   
Franklin. T. Wong. 333445555. 1945-12-08. 638 Voss, Cary, NC. M. 40000. 888665555. 5. 
Alicia. J. Zelaya. 999887777. 1958-07-19. 3321 Castle, Apex, NC. F. 25000. 987654321. 4.
Jennifer. S. Wallace. 987654321. 1931-06-20. 291 Berry, Garner, NC. F. 43000. 888665555. 4.
Ramesh. K. Narayan. 666884444. 1952-09-15. 975 Fire Oak, Angier, NC. M. 38000. 333445555. 5.
Joyce. A. English. 453453453. 1962-07-31. 5631 Rice, Raleigh, NC. F. 25000. 333445555. 5.
Ahmad. V. Jabbar. 987987987. 1959-03-29. 980 Dallas, Cary, NC. M. 25000. 987654321. 4.
James. E. Borg. 888665555. 1927-11-10. 450 Stone, Cary, NC. M. 55000. NULL. 1.
```

MySQL code:

```
mysql> load data local infile 'c:/employee upload2.txt' into table employee
    -> fields terminated by '.' lines terminated by '\n';
Query OK, 8 rows affected, 80 warnings (0.02 sec)
Records: 8  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 80
```

table looks like everything is trying to be crammed into the first field, but that can only hold the first 8 characters.
Any ideas?

Comment: You should show your query as well.  If you are using the default delimiters, this certainly would not work.

Comment: The address is a problem. You will probably need to reproduce this file with all fields quote-enclosed.

Answer (score 1):

Your data format is not good.  You need a consistent field delimiter if you want any hope of this working. You cannot use space-separated values without then escaping the spaces within other fields like address field (or name fields though not shown in sample data).

You also would not have the column headings in this file.

If you just used tab-separated values instead of space-separated, this would work just fine with the default `LOAD DATA INFILE` settings for field delimiters, escaping and line separators (assuming `\n` is actually your line separator)

The default MySQL behavior (if nothing is specified for delimiters, field encolsing characters, escape sequence or line start and end chracters is this:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
```

You can obviously use whatever characters you like in your data set as long as you match the query to use the same settings.

If you wanted to stick with space delimiters, you could do something like this

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
```

And put `"` around any fields that would potentially have spaces in them (or all fields) or escape all your spaces within field data with `\\`.  you would not need to escape the spaces if they were within a field enclosed by the double quotes.

Comment: so what character can I use at a consistent field delimiter?
Column heading was an error in copying and pasting.

Comment: @user1858304 As I mentioned above, if you just change out your space delimiter for a tab delimiter, you should be OK, as I doubt you are using tabs in any of your data fields that would need to be escaped.  I have added the default MySQL behavior to my answer above if this helps.

Comment: Maybe i'm doing something wrong, but its still not working, in fact everything I have in the text file tries to fill in the first field and the rest of the fields record null. I changed the field terminater to /t and that didn't work. Each field is seperated by a space.

Comment: @user1858304 Based on your latest edits to the question it seems you are trying to use `.` to terminate your fields.  But you still have spaces in there.  Maybe try using pipe delimiter `|` but make sure you removed spaces around pipes. Also you wouldn't need a pipe at the end of the row.